# Can layoutIfNeeded be called only once per loading the view - e.g. viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

A view's height in my view controller needs to change as the user interacts with the application. Sometimes the view needs to be larger in height and other times it needs to be shorter depending on the number of options a user has.

I have implemented a method to change the height depending on the state of the view, and I call this method in `viewDidLoad` to set the initial state, and I recall the method whenever the state changes.

However, the only time the view actually updates the layout is from the call in `viewDidLoad`. All other calls of my method do not update the view.

```
func updateContainerViewHeight(constant: CGFloat) {
    print("lets update")
    baseView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant).isActive = true
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant).isActive = true
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

FYI `print("let's update")` is printing in the console.

Comment: If you’re not seeing any change, then it’s likely that you have other, conflicting constraints in place. E.g. do you have old height constraints? If so, create outlet to those constraints and update their respective `constant` values.

Comment: By the way, that call to `setNeedsLayout` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As here

```
baseView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant).isActive = true
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant).isActive = true
```

every call adds new constraints which will cause conflicts , so create

1-

```
var baseCon,containCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

2-

```
baseCon = baseView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant)
baseCon.isActive = true
containCon = containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant)
containCo.isActive = true
```

3- Then play with constant

```
baseCon.constant = ////
```